# How to control the flow of service calls, using rxjs with Angular 9?

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, rxjs, observable

My code looks like this:

```
userContext: UserContext;
  userContext$ = this.http.get<UserContext>("assets/api/userContext.json", {}).pipe(
      shareReplay(1),
      tap((val: UserContext) => {
        this.userContext = val;
        console.log(this.userContext);
      })
  );
  userAnnouncements$ = this.http.post<Announcement>(this.userAnnouncementsService,
    {
      countryCode: this.userContext.countryCode, 
      companyGroupId: this.userContext.companyGroupId,
    }
  );
```

As we can clearly see 2nd Service (userAnnouncements$) needs the values received by 1st service (userContext$), now since they are async my userContext: UserContext; is empty while the 2nd service is executed.

I would also need the userContext.companyCode & GroupId for future calls, hence I need a way to keep it somewhere for subsequent calls.

I tried resolver and APP_INT... but then realized this is not the right purpose of both places.

Comment: Your `userContext` is fetched once and only once? If so, you could think of it as a singleton.

Comment: @VRoxa Yes fetched once and used in all subsequent calls, I guess the puzzle is about how\when to get it before other calls are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already are using `shareReplay`, only thing you have got to do is use the result of this Observable, wherever you want.

```
userAnnouncements$ = this.userContext$.pipe(mergeMap((userContextData) => {
    return this.http.post<Announcement>('someUrl',
        {
        countryCode: userContextData.countryCode, 
        companyGroupId: userContextData.companyGroupId,
        }
    );
}));
```

Comment: I think this is really the cleanest approach, It doesn't matter how many times I refer\use the data from this.userContext$.pipe it'll be executed only once and then data served from ShareReply. Trying it to implement it now to check for any glitches.

Answer (score 1):

I was expecting your answer.

If you `UserContext` is something it should be called once, as I mentioned, you can think of it as a singleton.
Fetch it once, then caches it inside your service.

```
class MyService {

    private _userContext: UserContext | undefined;

    constructor (private http: BackgroundService) { }

    userContext$ = this.http.get<UserContext>(`url`).then(ctx => {
        console.log(ctx);
        this._userContext = ctx;
        return ctx;
    });

    userAnnouncements$ = (): Promise<Announcement> => 
        this._userContext
            ? this.userAnnouncement(this._userContext)
            : this.userContext$.then(ctx => this.userAnnouncement(ctx));

    private userAnnouncement = (ctx: UserContext): Promise<Announcement> =>
        this.http.post<Announcement>(`url`, {
            countryCode: ctx.countryCode,
            companyGroupIp: ctx.companyGroupIp
        });
}

interface BackgroundService { // aka HttpClient
    get: <TResult>(url: string) => Promise<TResult>;
    post: <TResult>(url: string, body: any) => Promise<TResult>;
}
```

I just mocked up the `HttpClient` just for me to compile it properly. You can forget about it.

The point is, you service class has an inner property `UserContext`. Any call to `userContext$` will provide this object and caches inside the service.
If a call to `userAnnouncements$` is done, then it uses the cached `UserContext`. Whenever a call to `userAnnouncements$` is done before any call to `userContext$`, so `UserContext` is *null* or *undefined*, then, a previous call to `userContext$` is done to fulfill the property.

`_userContext` may be static depending on your dependency injection policies. If you want to every service to store their own `_userContext`, fine. Even if `MyService` is singleton, then `_userContext` should not be static. Otherwise, an static `_userContext` is needed to share across all the service instances.

Moreover, you could overload the `userAnnouncements$` to to force a `UserContext` refetch. That would be interesting, if needed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the trivial way, but since he is already using `shareReplay` he would not need to do this. See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxujzv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Open console for logs, and Network tab for XHR requests, you would see the logs on every click, but XHR only once.

Comment: Are you performing the `UserContext` call once even with two calls to `userAnnouncements$`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. As shown in the added example, I am calling the API only once, doesn't matter how many times I click the button.

Comment: @VRoxa yes ShareReplay does everything (related to caching) for your, hence allow's you to write cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for but you could use switchMap

```
userContext: UserContext;
  userContext$ = this.http.get<UserContext>("assets/api/userContext.json", {}).pipe(
      tap((val: UserContext) => {
        this.userContext = val;
        console.log(this.userContext);
      }),
      switchMap((val: UserContext) => {
          return this.http.post<Announcement>(this.userAnnouncementsService, 
          {
              countryCode: val.countryCode,
              companyGroupId: val.companyGroupId
          });
      }
  );
```

Then you only have one subscription